# Google maps autocomplete js is working on localhost but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, heroku, autocomplete, gmaps4rails

I'm a junior ruby on rails developer. I developed a web app that uses Google maps javascript API and I use the autocomplete function on a form input.

The autocomplete works fine on localhost but does not work anymore after deploying on heroku.

Here is my html.erb below. For your perfect information, the form is in the page footer. This form is partially hidden and the only visible part corresponds to a button used to upload a video file. Once this button has been clicked and the video file has been chosen, I display a modal containing the rest of the form. That's where the 'text_field_tag' (with the id =  "user_input_autocomplete_address") is displayed and where the autocomplete should work.

```html
<% if user_signed_in? %>

<div class="footer-check hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <div class="container text-right">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="footer-home active">
          <%= link_to root_path do %>
            <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-search">
        <!-- later put link_to reviews_path -->
          <%= link_to search_path do %>
            <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-button">
        <%= simple_form_for(Review.new) do |f| %>
          <div id="add_video_image_btn">
            <label for="review_video", class="add_video_image"><%= image_tag "plus.png" %></label>
            <%= f.input :video, label: false, input_html: { accept: ".mp4, .mov, .m4v, .wmv, .webm, .avi", class: 'hidden'} %>
            <%= f.input :video_cache, as: :hidden, class: "add_video_image file required" %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-likes">
          <%= link_to dashboard_users_path do %>
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <% end %>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-user">
          <%= link_to user_path(current_user) do %>
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Beginning Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div id="add_video_form_step2">
        <%= f.error_notification %>

        <fieldset class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0;">

          <div class="section">
            Place
          </div>
          <div class="inner-wrap">
            <div id="">
              <%= text_field_tag :place, nil, class: 'form-control', id: 'user_input_autocomplete_address', placeholder: 'Start typing...', size: 80 %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="section">
            Comment
          </div>
          <div class="inner-wrap">
            <%= text_field_tag :comment, nil, class:'form-control', placeholder: 'Food is good but the place is a bit noisy', size: 80 %>
          </div>

          <div class="inner-wrap" style="padding:15px;">
            <div class="emoji-toggle emoji-happy">
              <input type="checkbox" id="toggle1" class="toggle" name="review[mood]" value="false">
              <div class="emoji"></div>
              <label for="toggle1" class="well"></label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="">
            <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary form-control", id: "click-trigger" %>
          </div>

          <%= hidden_field_tag :name, id: 'name' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :street_number, id: 'street_number' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :route, id: 'route' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :locality, id: 'locality' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :administrative_area_level_1, id: 'administrative_area_level_1' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :postal_code, id: 'category_0' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :country, id: 'country' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :formatted_address, id: 'formatted_address' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :phone_number, id: 'phone_number' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :website, id: 'website' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :gplace_id, id: 'gplace_id' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :category_0, id: 'category_0' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :category_1, id: 'category_1' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :category_2, id: 'category_2' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :category_3, id: 'category_3' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :category_4, id: 'category_4' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :category_5, id: 'category_5' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :hours_open_day_0, id: 'hours_open_day_0' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :hours_open_day_1, id: 'hours_open_day_1' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :hours_open_day_2, id: 'hours_open_day_2' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :hours_open_day_3, id: 'hours_open_day_3' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :hours_open_day_4, id: 'hours_open_day_4' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :hours_open_day_5, id: 'hours_open_day_5' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :hours_open_day_6, id: 'hours_open_day_6' %>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>

<!--End Modal -->

<!-- Start of js to display the modal -->
<!-- NB: the autocomplete module is in assets/javascript/autocomplete.js -->
<%= content_for :after_js do %>
  <script>
    $('#review_video').change(function(){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
<!-- End of js to display the modal -->
```

The footer (gathering the modal and the form) is called within a layouts/application.html.erb view, which is below. You'll see that I use Google API key in there (hidden in application.yml)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= meta_title %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <!-- Start Favicon -->

    <%= favicon_link_tag '_/app/assets/images/favicon.ico' %>

    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="<%= image_path 'ms-icon-144x144.png' %>">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <!-- end Favicon -->

    <meta name="description" content="<%= meta_description %>">

    <!-- Facebook Open Graph data -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="<%= meta_title %>" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<%= request.original_url %>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<%= meta_image %>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<%= meta_description %>" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<%= meta_title %>" />

    <!-- Twitter Card data -->
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="<%= DEFAULT_META["twitter_account"] %>">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="<%= meta_title %>">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="<%= meta_description %>">
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="<%= DEFAULT_META["twitter_account"] %>">
    <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="<%= meta_image %>">

    <!-- Google+ Schema.org markup -->
    <meta itemprop="name" content="<%= meta_title %>">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="<%= meta_description %>">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="<%= meta_image %>">



    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <!-- start Mixpanel -->
    <script type="text/javascript">(function(e,b){if(!b.__SV){var a,f,i,g;window.mixpanel=b;b._i=[];b.init=function(a,e,d){function f(b,h){var a=h.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],h=a[1]);b[h]=function(){b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}var c=b;"undefined"!==typeof d?c=b[d]=[]:d="mixpanel";c.people=c.people||[];c.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==d&&(a+="."+d);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};c.people.toString=function(){return c.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};i="disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config reset people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");
      for(g=0;g<i.length;g++)f(c,i[g]);b._i.push([a,e,d])};b.__SV=1.2;a=e.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src="undefined"!==typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL?MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL:"file:"===e.location.protocol&&"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js".match(/^\/\//)?"https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js":"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js";f=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];f.parentNode.insertBefore(a,f)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);
      mixpanel.init("ENV['MIXPANEL_TOKEN']");
    </script>
    <!-- end Mixpanel -->

  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'shared/flashes' %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=#{ENV['GMAP_BROWSER_KEY']}" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= yield :after_js %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Last, the javascript code allowing the autocomplete on the input (having "user_input_autocomplete_address" as id) is in assets/javascript/autocomplete.js and is the following :

```js
function initializeAutocomplete(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  console.log('coucou');
  if (element) {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element, { types: ['geocode', 'establishment'] });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', onPlaceChanged);
  }
}

function onPlaceChanged() {
  var place = this.getPlace();

  console.log(place);  // Uncomment this line to view the full object returned by Google API.

  for (var i in place.address_components) {
    var component = place.address_components[i];
    // console.log(component.types);
    for (var j in component.types) {  // Some types are ["country", "political"]
      var type_element = document.getElementById(component.types[j]); // Returns the div with their differents ids or null if the id doesnt exist
      // console.log(document.getElementById(component.types[j]));
      if (type_element) {
        type_element.value = component.long_name;
      }
    }
  }

  var formatted_address = document.getElementById('formatted_address');
  // console.log(international_phone_number);
  if (formatted_address) {
    formatted_address.value = place.formatted_address;
  }

  for (var i in place.types) {
    // console.log(place.types);
    // console.log(i);
    // console.log(place.types[i]);
    var type_content = document.getElementById('category_' + i); // Returns the div with their differents ids or null if the id doesnt exist
    // console.log(document.getElementById(component.types[j]));
    if (type_content) {
      console.log(place.types[i]);
      type_content.value = place.types[i];
    }
  }

  var international_phone_number = document.getElementById('phone_number');
  // console.log(international_phone_number);
  if (international_phone_number) {
    international_phone_number.value = place.international_phone_number;
  }

  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  if (name) {
    name.value = place.name;
  }

  var gplace_id = document.getElementById('gplace_id');
  if (gplace_id) {
    gplace_id.value = place.place_id;
  }

  var website = document.getElementById('website');
  if (website) {
    website.value = place.website;
  }

  for (var i in place.opening_hours.weekday_text) {
    var hours_open_in_db = place.opening_hours.weekday_text[i];
    var hours_open_in_form = document.getElementById('hours_open_day_' + i);
    if (hours_open_in_form) {
      hours_open_in_form.value = hours_open_in_db;
    }
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  initializeAutocomplete('user_input_autocomplete_address');
});
```

In order to deploy all this on heroku, I already did the following :

1. "heroku run db:migrate" in the terminal (because I had some pending
   migrations);
2. "figaro heroku:set -e production" in the terminal, in order to push all my API keys to heroku (I also checked that these keys are indeed in heroku's config vars).
3. in Google's developer console, within my project and within Google map javascript API, I ensured that my browser key is allowed for both my locahost and my domain name. In order to be very precise, I am using the same key for my locahost and my domain name. Until now, the only thing I have not managed to do yet, in Google's console, is to prove that I own my domain name.
4. I checked I have not reached any of my API quotas yet.
5. Within my autocomplete.js file, I used some console.log in order to find out, in my browser's inspector, what parts of the code are working. It seems that everything works except the console.logs that are in the 'OnPlaceChange' callback, since Gmap's autocomplete suggestions are not shown... ;
6. I know that not seeing the autocomplete suggestions is not a problem of z-index associated to the .pac-container css element, since I already had to fix this and since Gmaps suggestions cannot be reached thanks to my keyboard arrows.
7. I read this post about geocomplete ([geocomplete for rails 4 not working in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500862/geocomplete-for-rails-4-not-working-in-heroku)) and tried to precompile my assets. That did not lead to any change.
8. In my browser inspector (in the 'network' section), when I write something in my form input, every new letter pressed on the keyboard triggers a new request. These requests names are 'AutocompletionService.GetPredictions.....'. In the "headers" section, I can see they are https requests to googleapis, with get methods and 200 status code. In the "response" section, I can see there seems to be a error with my API keys since the message is :

```html
/**/_xdc_._ty4oqn && _xdc_._ty4oqn( [3,null,null,"This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=_ Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_ For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key"] )
```

I followed the link in the error message, leading me to Google's console, and I get back to my project and API keys, which are settled both server-side and browser-side. Once again, the only thing i did not managed to do in Google's console was to prove I own my domain name.

Is this last point the origin of the issue (and in this case I guess I need some help from my hosting services) or do you guys see another mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I has same issue too.
just goto google console, enable the "Google Places API Web Service", then it will solved the problem.

Comment: you are completely right! Thanks a lot! So, how to explain it? I guess that, because I'm looking for both geocoded (addresses) and establishments, Google Places API Web Service" is implicitly called, in addition to Google Javascript API. Am I right?

Comment: saved my day after 5 hours tearing hair out.  thanks, buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Google Places API Web Service" on Google API Console. It solved my problem when the website worked on localhost, but don't at Locaweb server.