# Google Location Autocomplete not working under different folder

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, autocomplete, localhost

I have an **angularjs** web app running on **localhost:8085** and am using **Google Maps Autocomplete**. I created an API key for this app and set it up to accept requests from a bunch of different urls, including

http://localhost:8085/*

Autocomplete **was working just fine**, until another developer complained that it was not auto-completing on his machine. Then I noticed that, if I simply **rename the folder** where my project is, autocomplete stops doing it's job. **No error message** on the console, it just doesn't find addresses as I type.

So... It works here:

http://localhost:8085/my_app/

But not here:

http://localhost:8085/myapp/

I'm using ui-router and the component works just fine on any route inside http://localhost:8085/my_app/

There's nothing in my code that has anything to do with the path name. None of that is hardcoded anywhere.

Ah, the code works fine on a "proper" web server (with a registered domain) we have for tests. There I can rename the project folder at will. Only on localhost I have this issue.

On the other developer's computer no folder name ever works. He uses port 8090 -- I also have this port being accepted for localhost on Google API manager.

We are on **Windows 10**, using **LightTPD** webserver.

What can be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking a bit more I found something that worked for us here: [Google maps autocomplete js is working on localhost but not on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186827/google-maps-autocomplete-js-is-working-on-localhost-but-not-on-heroku?rq=1)

Namely, turn on Google Places API Web Service. Don't know why sometimes autocomplete was working without that, though.